# ColorPicker and ColorView

Tags: android, colors, color-picker

So I got this button and this ColorView on my .xml layout as you see in the left snapshoot, I want to fill the background of the ColorView square with the color chosen by the user in the dialog that you see on the right snapshoot.

[image][image]

My .xml code:

```
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/color_button"
       style="@style/buttonStyle"
       android:layout_width="280sp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/color_view"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
       android:onClick="showColorPickerDialog"
       android:text="Color" />

    <es.lost2found.lost2foundUI.pickerUI.ColorView
       android:id="@+id/color_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
       android:background="@color/otherUserMsgColor">
    </es.lost2found.lost2foundUI.pickerUI.ColorView>
```

The onClick method called on the button is this one:

```
public void showColorPickerDialog(View v) {
    ColorPickerUI colorpicker = new ColorPickerUI();
    colorpicker.build()
            .title(R.string.color_dialog_title)
            .colorPreset(Color.BLACK)
            .allowCustom(true)
            .show(this, "dialog");
}
```

I'm using the [QuadFlask ColorPicker](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker), I don't know if there's a method to do what I want, I've been searching on the repository and I didn't find it.

If there's any way to get what I want with other colorPicker let me know please, any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got it, I've used `onColorSet()` method on my ColorPicker class, I put here the code in case someone need it

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.color_view);
view.setBackgroundColor(mSelectedColor);
```

All I have to do was use the variable mSelectedColor and setBackground with it.                                                                    Thank you so much to @Pavneet_Singh for your help, I'm sure someone will use your code!

Comment: I didn't know that you are using it in a fragment but glad that you found the solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to add listener , which will be triggered when a color is either selected or positive button is pressed so use it like

```
public void showColorPickerDialog(View v) {
    ColorPickerUI colorpicker = new ColorPickerUI();
    colorpicker
            .title(R.string.color_dialog_title)
            .colorPreset(Color.BLACK)
            .allowCustom(true)// change color on continuous selection
            .addOnColorChangedListener(new OnColorChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onColorChanged(int selectedColor) {
                    findViewById(R.id.color_button).setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
                }
            })// change color on selection
            .addOnColorSelectedListener( new OnColorSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {
                    findViewById(R.id.color_button).setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
                }
            })
            .build().show(this, "dialog");
}
```

Comment: I get an error on `setPositiveButton` "Cannot resolve method setPositiveButton(java.lang.String, anonymous com.flask.colorpicker.builder.ColorPickerClickListener)"

Comment: I am glad that I could help..happy coding